# i can't select element with querySelector when component is mounted vue js

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

i'm using Nuxt.js and Vuetify, i'm trying to select an element with

```
mounted(){
   console.log(this.$el.querySelector('#scroll-target'));
}
```

but i'm getting null in the console after the page compiling. 
when i do this i can see my element :

```
mounted(){
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log(this.$el.querySelector('#scroll-target'));
    }.bind(this), 2000);
}
```

knowing that in the documentation it's mentioned that the $el is created before the mounted
so can one explain to me why this happen ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it should work to me, can we see the template? I also just tested it, and it works as expected in my vue enviroment.

The only situation where i seem to return null, is if the component is not rendered for whatever reason, v-if conditions etc.

Is it possible you can paste your template?  Thanks

Comment: ah yess i forget i have this element inside <div v-if="show"> thank you

Comment: awesome no problem :)